# JQUERY AJAX POST ERROR 500 any idea? I'm trying to insert records into

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

CODEIGNITER METHOD

```
public function agregar_post(){

            $nombre = $this->post('nombre');
            $mail          = $this->post('mail');
            $telefono      = $this->post('telefono');
            $password      = $this->post('password');
            $nivel_listado = $this->post('nivel_listado');
```

// Store he whole data into $data

```
$data = array(
                'id'           => '',
                'nombre'       => $nombre,
                'mail'         => $mail,
                'telefono'     => $telefono,
                'password'     => $password,
                'api_key'      => '',
                'nivel_listados' => $nivel_listado 
                );
            $query = $this->db->insert('cliente',$data);
```

// Check if insert is succes

```
if ($query) 
{
    $this->output->set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.verdulero.com", false); // header allow
    $this->response($query,201);
 }else
     {
         $this->response(null,404);
     }
 }
```

//JQUERY AJAX

```
$("#frmAddClient").submit(function (event){
                event.preventDefault();
                var dataForm = $(this).serialize(); 


// ajax to insert a new product
                $.ajax({
                    type: $(this).attr('method'), // METHOD FROM FORM
                    url: $(this).attr('action'), // URL FROM FORM
                    crossDomain: true,
                    data: dataForm,
                    success: function(){
                        alert();
                    } 
                }); 



// CLEAN THE FORM AFTER INSERT
                $("#frmAddClient")[0].reset();
            });
```

// HTML

```
    <form name="frmAddClient" id="frmAddClient" method="post" action="<?= $addClient ?>" class="form-horizontal">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Email" class="col-sm-4  control-label">Correo electronico:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></span>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Email" name="mail" placeholder="Verdulero@example.com" value="" autofocus required>
              </div>                         
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Nombre" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Nombre:</label>
           <div class="col-sm-4">
             <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Juan Verdura" value=""  required>                  
              </div>
            </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Telefono" class="col-sm-4  control-label">Telefono:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone-alt"></span></span>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Telefono" name="telefono" placeholder=" 555 555 555" value="" required>
              </div>                         
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Password" class="col-sm-4  control-label">Password:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></span>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="Password" name="password" placeholder="Password" value="" required>
              </div>                         
            </div>
    </div>

     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="nivel_listado" class="col-sm-4  control-label">Nivel Listado:</label>
           <div class="col-sm-4">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></span>
                  <select class="form-control" name='nivel_listado' id='nivel_listado'>
                    <option value=''>Elija</option>
                    <option value='1'>Usuario nivel  1</option>
                    <option value='2'>Usuario nivel 2</option>
                    <option value='3'>Usuario nivel 3</option>
                    <option value='4'>Nivel administrador</option>
                  </select>
              </div>                         
            </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-6">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit" id="Submit_User" value="Insertar nuevo usuario"/> 
        </div>
   </div> 

</form>
```

Comment: More details? What, where, why

Comment: Can't you check the returned error with firebug or error log in CI? 500 is a Internal Server Error, usually in your php, but all seems ok, is the query returning ok? what happens if you dump the response? We need more info.

Comment: Here is the error..  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
Admin:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.api.verdulero.com/index.php/api/Cliente/agregar. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.verdulero.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$this->input->post()` instead of `$this->post()`

```
$nombre = $this->input->post('nombre');
$mail   = $this->input->post('mail');
$telefono  = $this->input->post('telefono');
$password  = $this->input->post('password');
$nivel_listado = $this->input->post('nivel_listado');
```